# Illustrator: how to get a blank artboard?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, interface-design, artboard

This is what my screen looks like. I want a white artboard with no extras. How do I get rid of the green ruler and boxes?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### Step by step solution with pictures

1. Edit the artboard (Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter <kbd>O</kbd>)
2. Press those three buttons to turn the green lines off:

   [image: Illustrator screenshot]
3. Press <kbd>V</kbd> to come out of editing mode

#### Now, to turn off the Rulers

1. Click "View" in the menu bar
2. Select `rulers` > `Hide Video Rulers`:

   [image: Illustrator screenshot]

Comment: It would be better to add the screenshots and text as actual text in your post; or at least give it a white background, [I can't read the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btt62.png).

Comment: @Cai Thanks for the suggestion. I have added images and have written  text in my post.

Comment: Will they stay for every artboard or do I have to do that every single time?

Comment: @Nicholas it is a option in the template file you open. If you open a different template or make a new template file then they wont be there.

Comment: @Nicholas No they won't appear unless you put them on again.
But they might appear when you open a new file/artboard under film and video. Rest of the template options won't turn them on.